# Accidentally dropped a screw down conduit

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, conduit

As part of my basement finishing project I installed a 100 amp sub panel by running 3-3-3-5 copper SER cable through 1.5" PVC conduit. After finishing the installation I accidentally dropped a small screw down the conduit. I tried fishing it out with a magnet but didn't have any luck. Should I go through all the trouble of pulling the cable to remove the screw or leave it be?

Comment: Did you try a shop vac?

Comment: You probably have a ~99% of the screw never causing a problem.  Screws have pointy ends that go though insulation the other 1% of the time.  Powerful magnets as found in old hard drives might wiggle the screw out from the outside of the conduit.

Comment: And why did you run *cable* through conduit? And why *copper* instead of aluminum? Depending on how long the cable is, pulling it out, selling it for the copper and putting in aluminum wires (not cable) might be cost-effective.

Comment: Or compressed air from the opposite end?

Comment: There was no way to get a good seal with a shop vac. @crip659 I took your advice and tried running a magnet along the outside of the conduit but it wasn't catching. SER cable has a sheath that allows it to be treated like Romex which saved me from having to run conduit all the way to the subpanel. As for the copper I saved so much money doing it myself that the price didn't really matter. I haven't worked with aluminum and decided to go with a material I've worked with before and am comfortable with.

Answer (score 4):

crip659's first comment scared me enough that I decided to rerun the SER. Fished out the screw with a flexible magnetic tool once the conduit was empty.

Comment: Well you probably have a lot more conduit pulling practice than most DIY homeowners now!  :)